# Unity switch between images when clicking a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a little project with an image. I have a button next to it and a few other sprites. Now I want to click on the button which should be able to switch to the other sprites I have. Like click on the button, change to other sprite and so on with 4 sprites and then it starts again with the first one.
That is the code I have now which should work for one sprite (I put it in as an image since it doesn't work somehow even if I press ctrl+k).

I hope someone of you can help me out :)

Kind regards

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e39C.png)

Comment: Better to post your code in text into the text editor provided.  If you need help with that browse the help sites, i.e. start with the little ? circle in the upper right corner of this window.  I should be a [mcve].

Comment: Still didn't make it.
Anyway, it is only like 3 lines of code I have yet.
public Image original;
    public Sprite newSprite;
And a new method which has this:
original.sprite = newSprite;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is what you want.

```cs
    public List<Sprite> spriteCollection = new List<Sprite>();
    public Image original;

    private int m_spriteIndex = 0;
    private int m_spriteCount = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        m_spriteCount = spriteCollection.Count;
        original.sprite = spriteCollection[m_spriteIndex];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Bind button
    /// </summary>
    public void NewImage()
    {
        m_spriteIndex++;
        if (m_spriteIndex == m_spriteCount)
            m_spriteIndex = 0;
        original.sprite = spriteCollection[m_spriteIndex];        
    }
```